# retrieve row from multiple row of table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve data from three table

for example

Table_1 : NAME_A

```
PD_ID 
 A
 B
 C
```

Table_2 : NAME_B Primary_key PD_ID,EV_N

```
PD_ID   EV_N   EV_DEC
 A      1       one
 A      2       Two
 B      1       one
 B      2       Two
 B      3       THREE
 C      1       one
 C      2       Two
```

Table_3 : NAME_C  Primary key PD_ID

```
PD_ID, FFT_NAME, FFT_DESC
A        XY       XY_DESC
B        ZY       ZY_DESC
B        XY       XY_DESC
C        ZY       ZY_DESC
C        XY       XY_DESC
C        PY       PY_DESC
```

Required Output

```
PD_ID    EV_N   EV_DEC  FFT_NAME  FFT_DESC
 A        1      ONE      XY        XY_DESC 
 A        2      TWO       
 B        1      ONE      ZY        ZY_DESC 
 B        2      TWO      XY        XY_DESC 
 B        3      THREE    
 C        1      ONE      ZY        ZY_DESC
 C        2      Two      XY        XY_DESC
                          PY        PY_DESC
```

Comment: Hi, it’s an example - you should add the logic to the question... too hard to understand what you are trying to do...  it seems that you need to join the tables while taking the rownum into account?

Comment: So what determines the order of records from `Table_3`? It's not controlled by any of the posted columns.

Comment: What is your attempt so far?

Comment: @cohenjo Thanks for replying.Actually I want to display two table data but in both table contain different number of record  for same PID.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I  m not sure how to achieve this after using join it is not poosible.

Comment: can u please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to range records in both tables and then use this range numbers in a full outer join:

```
with
t1 as (
  select 'A' pd_id from dual union all
  select 'B' pd_id from dual union all
  select 'C' pd_id from dual
),
t2 as (
  select 'A' pd_id, 1 EV_N, 'one' EV_DEC from dual union all
  select 'A' pd_id, 2 EV_N, 'two' EV_DEC from dual union all
  select 'B' pd_id, 1 EV_N, 'one' EV_DEC from dual union all
  select 'B' pd_id, 2 EV_N, 'two' EV_DEC from dual union all
  select 'B' pd_id, 3 EV_N, 'three' EV_DEC from dual union all
  select 'C' pd_id, 1 EV_N, 'one' EV_DEC from dual union all
  select 'C' pd_id, 2 EV_N, 'two' EV_DEC from dual
),
t3 as (
  select 'A' pd_id, 'XY' FFT_NAME, 'XY_DESC' FFT_DESC from dual union all
  select 'B' pd_id, 'ZY' FFT_NAME, 'ZY_DESC' FFT_DESC from dual union all
  select 'B' pd_id, 'XY' FFT_NAME, 'XY_DESC' FFT_DESC from dual union all
  select 'C' pd_id, 'ZY' FFT_NAME, 'ZY_DESC' FFT_DESC from dual union all
  select 'C' pd_id, 'XY' FFT_NAME, 'XY_DESC' FFT_DESC from dual union all
  select 'C' pd_id, 'PY' FFT_NAME, 'PY_DESC' FFT_DESC from dual
)
select coalesce(t22.pd_id,t33.pd_id) pd_id, 
       t22.ev_dec, 
       t33.FFT_NAME, 
       t33.FFT_DESC
from   (
        select pd_id, ev_n, ev_dec, row_number() over (partition by pd_id order by ev_n, ev_dec) rn
        from  t2
       ) t22 
         full join (
           select pd_id, FFT_NAME, FFT_DESC, row_number() over (partition by pd_id order by FFT_NAME, FFT_DESC) rn
           from   t3
         ) t33 
           on t22.pd_id = t33.pd_id
           and t22.rn = t33.rn
```

Comment: Good answer, minor notes: `row_number()` for T2 is not needed, seems like we should use `EV_N` for join. And in T3 number rows descending, to match required output. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/1133)

Answer (score 1):

This won't produce the exact output you specify but it will produce a consistent and predictable output:

```
select t1.PD_ID 
       ,   t2.EV_N
       ,   t2.EV_DEC
       ,   t2.FFT_NAME
       ,   t2.FFT_DESC
from  name_a t1
     cross join ( select coalesce(b.p_id, c.p_id) as p_id
                         , b.ev_n
                         , upper(b.ev_dec) as ev_dec
                         , c.fft_name
                         , c.fft_desc
                  from  ( select * from name_b ) b
                  full outer join 
                        ( select c.*
                                 , row_number() over (partition by c.p_id 
                                                      order by c.fft_name) as rn
                           from name_c c) c
                  on c.p_id = b._pid  
                  and c.rn = b.ev_n) t2
where t1.p_id = t2.p_id                     
order by t1.p_id
         , t2.ev_n nulls last
```